# How to handle processing failure with Azure functions after reading from CosmosDB change feed?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm planning to create an event-driven **Azure Cosmos DB trigger** in an **Azure Function** as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database)

Let's say I'm reading a list of 100 documents that have been recently changed and the checkpoint is **X**. Now, while processing this change feed, my Azure function failed somewhere in between, lets say document no 50. 
Will the checkpoint be reverted back to X and will my Azure function start processing all the documents again from the change feed back from the checkpoint X?

If NO, then is there a better way to handle the processing of change feed with the guarantee of processing it **at least once**?

Comment: have you found any solution?